# Change Australia travel dates after being granted a visa

Tags: visas, australia

I have been granted a visitors Visa for a holiday to Australia that was Originally to start this month Feb'20, but I have had to change my plans and will now not be going until Sept 21st with arrival in Sydney on the 23rd, the very day my visa runs out !! Is it possible to change the dates on my visa? I know that my visa is actually valid for my arrival that day (23rd), but if my flights happen to be delayed for some reason and don't arrive until after the 23rd I don't want to be refused entry ! Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is the ‘Entry Expiry Date’ and the ‘Stay For/Until Date’ of your visa?

Comment: My visa is valid from 23 Sept 2019 until 23rd Sept 2020 for a 3 month stay.

Answer (score 4):

You will almost assuredly be denied admittance if you arrive in Australia after your "Entry Expiry Date." If your flight to Australia is so delayed on departure that it will arrive in Australia after the "Extry Expiry Date," the airline will refuse to allow you to even board the flight.

A search of [Australia.gov.au](https://www.australia.gov.au/information-and-services/immigration-and-visas) returns nothing about amending or changing already-issued visas. That's because — as @k2moo4 notes in a comment —  Australia law does not permit the amendment or change of visas already issued.

That being so, your choices are:

- Go on your trip as now scheduled, and accept the risks that you will be late and denied entry.

or

- Change your trip dates so you'll arrive well before your "Entry Expiry Date"

or

- Apply for a new visa with different dates that will better accommodate your current trip plans.

Comment: Australian visas cannot be amended - see subsection 67(4) of the [Migration Act](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2019C00339/Html/Volume_1#_Toc28080302)

Comment: Thanks for the citation. I'll amend the answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, that's  exactly what I was after.